# How we reduce margin during page load

Tags: css, reactjs

On loading the `Register.js` screen, there is big space between Password text field and Register button. The space get decreases when the validation message displays and I happy with that one.

How can we apply less space during loading of Register screen, can we conditionally do that in css if there is no `className` `registerValidationText` apply this `margin-top` or something similar. ?

// Error tag to display the validation message:

```
<label>
   <span className="registerValidationText">{helperText}</span>
 </label>
```

[image]

//After validation message appears !.

[image]

**css**:

```
.submitButtonDiv{
  height:45px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

**React button div**:

```
<div className="submitButtonDiv formElement">
    <button type="submit" className="submitButton">Register</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that when error occurs you're displaying that error label.

I think you can do something like this

```
<div className="submitButtonDiv formElement" style={{margin: isError ? 'some other margin' : '65px 0 20px 0'}}>
<button type="submit" className="submitButton">Register</button></div>
```

Now you need to set one boolean flag isError to true while setting your error div display/visible.

So instead of adding margin from css, you can add it on condition based inside your component.

Comment: What do I need add in  `some other margin`  ?

Comment: I have removed the .submitButtonDiv {} from css and added as suggested in my component. But dont know what to add in 'some other margin'

Comment: Added `const [isError, setIsError] = useState(true); style={{margin: isError ? 'margin' : '75px 0 20px 0'}}`

Comment: in some other margin I meant to say whatever value you feel suitable for your UI.

Comment: You forgot to add the else part in conditional statement. Also you're setting error as true default value. Need to set it as false and from where you're setting error div as true there you need to call setIsError(true);

Comment: Sorry didn't get that. When loading the register screen the margin need to be reduced. So how can add the else part as suggested .

Comment: Ahh I see your addition of style syntax is incorrect, style={{margin: isError ? '75px 0 20px 0' : '20px 0 20px 0'}}. This is the correct way. Now when you load the screen, initially isError will be false(assuming that you initialize it with False) and then once the error is set, then margin will reset it's value with the syntax that I provided

Comment: `const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false); div className="submitButtonDiv formElement" style={{margin: isError ? '65px 0 20px 0' : '20px 0 20px 0'}}>
    <button type="submit" className="submitButton">Register</button>
 </div>`

Comment: All good now, as I have set fixed height for another parent div